# dfr TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Office' and 'str'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to concatenate some fields ex. When I do this in postman

```
{
"sem": "2",
"sy": "2021-2022",
"remarks": "test",
"resolution": "test",
"studid": "2012-5037"
}
```

this is the customuser I made
[image]
The **cl_itemid** shoud be OSA-2021-2022-2

```
class ClearanceItemSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ClearanceItem
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data["office"] = self.context["request"].user.officeid
    validated_data["recorded_by"] = self.context["request"].user.userid
    validated_data["cl_itemid"] = self.context["request"].user.officeid + '-' + validated_data.get('sy') + '-' + validated_data.get('sem')
    return super().create(validated_data)
```

above is the code

but it's throwing me an error ***TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Office' and 'str'***

if I use userid instead

```
validated_data["cl_itemid"] = self.context["request"].user.userid + '-' + validated_data.get('sy') + '-' + validated_data.get('sem')
```

it's working

```
321-05   2021-2022-2
```

What's happening here can somebody explain?

**Edit**: I added the models incase that's the problem

```
class ClearanceItem(models.Model):
cl_itemid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, default=get_default_id)
studid = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
office = models.ForeignKey('Office', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='office', blank=True, null=True)
sem = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
sy = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Office(models.Model):
office_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
office_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
office_head = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
designation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
office_parent = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
deptlogo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'office'
```

**Edit2**: I try to remove all fks from customuser to office and clearance_item to office and its working idk why

**Edit3**: I try to add str in `validated_data["cl_itemid"] = str(validated_data.get('office'))`

When I check the value it's (Office object (OSA)1), is there a way can i get only the OSA part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says clearly that cannot concatenate a string with an Office instance. So you should try to use `self.context["request"].user.officeid.office_id` because most likely on your customer model you have something like this

```
class Customer(models.model)
...
   officeid = models.ForeignKey('Office', db_column='officeid' ...)

...
```

Therefore accessing user.officeid will get you the entire Office object.

Comment: As a good practice you can try to rename the name of the field from `officeid` to `office`